# Get the the last inserted record in the code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an insert stored procedure likes this

```
 insert into Profile_Master(FirstName,LastName,Dob,Gender,MobileNo,Country,State,EmailId,Password)
 values 
(@FirstName,@LastName,@Dob,@Gender,@MobileNo,@Country,@State,@EmailId,@Password)
set @id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
return
end
```

I want to get the last inserted record in the code behind,how to catch the value?

```
            pid = cmd1.Parameters.Add("@id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
            pid.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
            int res = Convert.ToInt32(pid.Value);
            HttpContext.Current.Session["value"] = res.ToString();
```

here i am getting res as 0 so the values are not getting updated in the second page.

Comment: There is a great BLOG entry here: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/54/Getting-the-identity-of-the-most-recently-added-record

Comment: are you calling `cm1.ExecuteNonQuery()` before you read `pid` value?

Comment: I am calling  cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery() after reading the pid value.

Comment: you should call that before you read pid value.

Comment: I have to return cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery() value so it is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the stored procedure, you should have defined all of your parameters, including also the @ID with ParameterDirection.Output. This allows you to read the value of the parameter when your stored procedure exits.

Something like this

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING))
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    // Add all of your input parameters....

    SqlParameter pID = command.Parameters.Add
                 ("@ID",SqlDbType.Int);
    pID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    command.CommandText = "YourInsertProc";
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // After executing the stored procedure, the SCOPE_IDENTITY() value 
    // could be read from the parameter value.
    int result = Convert.ToInt32(pID.Value);    
}
```

if you need to pass the result to a second page you could use session variables

```
 Page.Session["EMailID"] = pID.Value;
```

and reread it in your second page

```
 if(Page.Session["EMailID"] != null)
    emailID = Convert.ToInt32(Page.Session["EMailID"]);
```

as a second possibility, pass the value using QueryString

```
  url = "secondPage.aspx?emailID=" + pID.Value.ToString();
```

getting it on "secondPage.aspx" with

```
  int emailID = Convert.ToInt32(Page.Request["emailID"]);
```

Comment: Updated the question...check once.

Comment: My scenario is that i have two pages one is just inserting the values and after the process it will go the next page where based on the ID i have to update some other values so how to do this from a stored procedure?Based on Emailid i want to update the values

Comment: I think you should get the result value immediately after the call to the stored procedure as shown above, then store it in some session variable where you could extract when the code behind of your second page executes.

Comment: As i am using a class file how can i define session value here?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `OUTPUT INSERTED` and `execute scalar`

Your Stored procedure

```
declare @idtbl table (id int)
insert into Profile_Master(FirstName,LastName,Dob,Gender,MobileNo,Country,
                            State,EmailId,Password)
output inserted.ID into @idtbl
values 
(@FirstName,@LastName,@Dob,@Gender,@MobileNo,@Country,@State,@EmailId,@Password)

SELECT id from @idtbl
```

In C# Code:

```
command.CommandText = "sp_name_here";
//add parameters
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
var id = command.ExecuteScalar();
HttpContext.Current.Session["value"] = id.ToString()
```

Comment: my answer is different than what you are doing above, check my answer once

Comment: yaa but i am doing like that so i dnt know why i am getting a null value?